# Read excel fie in java using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am struggling to read excel file in a dynamic web project I am developing. I could easily read it in a java application by following the same steps.

**What I did?**

I added these to build path

- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
- poi-3.13-20150939
- poi-examples
- poi-excelant
- poi-ooxml
- poi-ooxml-schemas
- poi-scratchpad

**Code:**

```
FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("file_location"));
XSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
XSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);                      
XSSFCell cell=null; 
for(int i=0;i<463;i++){
    cell = my_worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
    words[i]=cell.getStringCellValue();                                                          
    System.out.println(words[i]);          
}
my_xls_workbook.close();
```

**The Error**

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet vhealth.GetMed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
```

It is pretty long but this is the gist of it

**The Question**

I want to know how to solve this and as I mentioned it works in another similar java file after following the same steps. I want to integrate it in the web app. I've also tried calling the routine which imports the database in Java from the WebApp(which uses tomcat if that helps) still no luck.

Comment: Do you also have added the jars to your classpath?

Comment: I added them in build path

Comment: Might this be a common problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687130/classnotfoundexception-while-loading-class-in-tomcat-using-custom-classloader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add jar files not only in the build path. You need obviously to have the same files in your war module in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

P.S. I think you don't need poi-examples jar.

Comment: I copied all jar files at C:\Users\name\workspace\Doget\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib where DoGet is the name of the webapp. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I'll remove the extra jars once it works, though I think the solution will be something similar to what you mentioned. I am using eclipse if that helps.

Comment: @user3420463 Please, check are there those jars in the result war deployed  on tomcat server.

Comment: How to do so? Sorry I am new to tomcat. I am googling it btw.

Comment: @user3420463 Check your tomcat folder: tomcat-dir/webapps/[your app name]/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: The webapps folder does not contain anything related to my app name. I've made the app using eclipse, so it is in the eclipse workspace

Comment: @user3420463 Please, try to export a war file and deploy it on tomcat server: [How to create an war file in Eclipse without ant or maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032421/how-to-create-an-war-file-in-eclipse-without-ant-or-maven)

Comment: Phew!!, Ok deployed it and the jar files are present

Comment: Btw this might sound silly...now if I make a change in eclipse it will reflect in the exported project? I don't need to export again?

Comment: @user3420463 You need to export it again